# Error when publishing to iOS with AIR 4 "ios publishing requires files which are not installed."

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a game I to export to iPhone 5, but only AIR 3.2 was listed in Flash CS6 for me.  I updated to 4.0.0.168 by downloading the sdk, extracting it to a folder, and adding it in Help>Manage AIR SDK.

But when I try to publish to iOS with it, I got this error: "ios publishing requires files which are not installed. Please quit Flash Professional and run the original installer to ensure that all optional components are installed."

I searched around and found this forum about it:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3909140#3909140

The last post on the forum has some hints to why this happens, but I tried targetting 3.2 again and then changing back to 4 and that didn't work.

Maybe I need to install some extra AIR files to upgrade from 3.2 to 4?

ANSWERED:  Turns out I downloaded AIR SDK for MAC no PC and was trying to use that.  Yep. That was a fun waste of 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't see the answer above (I almost missed it), make sure you are using the correct AIR SDK for your platform.

If you Google "air sdk" and click the "Download Now" link that shows up under the top search result, it will happily download the Windows version even if you are on a Mac. (If you're on Windows, like the OP, it's obviously not hard to end up accidentally downloading the Mac version.)

Going to the AIR SDK manager in Flash also happily adds it as the latest version of AIR, and you can even enter everything in the dialog box for "AIR 15.0.0.249 for iOS Settings..." -- but then when you try to publish you get the message above.

Thank you, OP, you just saved me at least part of the 3 hours that I too would have spent on this.

Adobe, this is a really unacceptable glitch.